# share folder c# - not work

Tags: c#, share

I try to share a local folder in my computer - The code is shown below , taken from the Internet and appear in many places, but not working .
Am I missing something ?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a ManagementClass object
        ManagementClass managementClass = new
        ManagementClass("Win32_Share");
        // Create ManagementBaseObjects for in and out parameters
        ManagementBaseObject inParams =
        managementClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");
        ManagementBaseObject outParams;
        // Set the input parameters
        inParams["Description"] = "My Files Share";
        inParams["Name"] = "My Files Share";
        inParams["Path"] = @"C:\folder";
        inParams["Type"] = 0x0; // Disk Drive
                                // Invoke the method on the ManagementClass object
        outParams = managementClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams,
        null);
         //Check to see if the method invocation was successful
        if ((uint)(outParams.Properties["ReturnValue"].Value) != 0)
        {
           throw new Exception("Unable to share directory.");
       }
    }
```

Comment: What is Return value you get?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in sharefolder.exe

Additional information: Unable to share directory.

Comment: I'm looking for a simple code that work. only local folder, just to share. can't understand why it is so hard to do

Comment: I tried all sorts of other types of code from the Internet , none of them worked

Comment: What is the value of outParsma.Properties["returnvalue"]

Comment: Remove the try catch and write it to the console

Comment: There is no try and catch in this code.

Comment: Sorry I mean do not throw an error just get the value returned

Answer (score 0):

First of all , the problem was a permission. I'v tried to do net share through CMD and it also did not work, only when I run CMD as administrator share operation worked.

The same thing in C # , Visual Studio you MUST run as an administrator, then it works. Here's my code:

```
try
        {
            ManagementClass managementClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_Share");
            ManagementBaseObject inParams = managementClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");
            inParams["Description"] = Description;
            inParams["Name"] = ShareName;
            inParams["Path"] = folderPath;
            inParams["Type"] = 0; //Disk Drive
            inParams["MaximumAllowed"] = null;
            inParams["Password"] = null;
            inParams["Access"] = null;

            ManagementBaseObject outParams;
            outParams = managementClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);

            if ((uint)(outParams.Properties["ReturnValue"].Value) != 0)
                throw new Exception();
            ManagementObject share = new ManagementObject(managementClass.Path + ".Name='" + ShareName + "'");
        }

        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must run the program as administrator", "N.U.C", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            Environment.Exit(1);

        }
```

Comment: I'd go even further: i'd find out whether you're running the process as administrator and if not, start the process itself again with `startInfo.Verb = "runas";`.

Answer (score 0):

The code it's ok. If what you want it's to debug the program with your IDE it's pretty simple, if you are using Visual Studio as IDE, just run VS with Administrator right and open your project.